# ui-select2 problems with initSelection

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-ng-repeat

hi guys i have a problem when i try to move my app to use ui-select2.
Here is my old app that use ui.directives:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gyjNQU8moW1aykZVKR61?p=preview
and when i try to remove old 0.4.0 angular-ui and move to ui-select2 i change on app module definition ui.directives to ui.select2. Here is the example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9dl1LZ0nfVBqRNYfSEN?p=preview

on the second one is not calling the initSelection from select2. Anyone know what can be?